# Why "Wrap Text" turn on when copying from DataGridView to Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I am working with C# in Visual Studio 2012.

I have a windows form application which has a `DataGridView` control with rows. I select all rows in the `DataGridView` control, press Ctrl+C, then in Excel I paste it. All the rows are successfully copied in Excel. But what I see is the "**Wrap Text**" turn on in Excel.

Why "**Wrap Text**" turn on in this case?

Is it possible to copy and "**Wrap Text**" does not turn on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of excel when paste data. It keeps the column width and and wrap text and makes the height auto size. You can stop this behavior in excel not in your C# program.

As a workaround you can paste using `Match Destination Formatting` from paste options. (the item that I showed in the image with red rectangle around)

[image]

Comment: How can I change the default behaviour of excel for wrap text?

Comment: I think `Match Destination Formatting` will do the trick for you, but if you don't like to use it, the only way that makes it possible to change this default  behavior is creating a macro that changes the format of those cells after each change.

Comment: `Paste Special` looks easier option

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, `Paste Special` opens an additional, but it depends on the user preference :)

Comment: By the way, It will be great if you kindly vote for the answers that you mark as accepted :)