# Datagridview not displaying tab character

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, datatable

I use a visual basic program to get information from another program, which we'll call ProgramX.

ProgramX has built in functionality to generate tab-delimited tables, which many users copy over to Excel. My goal(which I've acheived) is to generate and collect upwards of 1,000 of these tables and have the results ready for the user to copy/paste into Excel all at once instead of one at a time. My Dataset keeps the tab-delimited records just as I would like them.

The issue is that when I display my dataset/datatable in my datagridview, all tab characters are removed. When the results are copied/pasted into Excel they take up one column instead of automatically breaking out. I have been using datagridview to preview results/copy to clipboard; Is there any way to retain the tabs in this view?

Expected Result: Result 1 [tab] Result 2 [tab] Result 3

Result in datatable: Result 1 [tab] Result 2 [tab] Result 3

Result in datagridview: Result 1Result 2Result 3

If the only way to achieve this is to copy directly from my datatable, I have seen a few posts on how to accomplish that. Thanks!

Comment: One, you are displaying all those tables in datagridview? Two, show how you defined your dataset. Three, what you mean by tab character? Text is not indented? Four, show the way you are copying to excel.

Comment: Claudius, 1. They are merged into one table and shown in datagridview. 2. One column, string. 3. Some space between groups of text, particularly useful because excel recognizes it as "start putting this in a different column" when pasting. 4. me.dgv.selectall() clipboard.setdataobject(me.dgv.getclipboardcontent())

Comment: Wouldn't be better to have more than one column in datagridview. You wouldn't have any problems there. If not maybe replace some space in between text with Chr(9) which is a tab and this statement is false: "Some space between groups of text, particularly useful because excel recognizes it as "start putting this in a different column" when pasting"

Comment: Also what this means:  "Is there any way to retain the tabs in this view?"

Comment: It would be more ideal to have multiple columns in the datatable/datagridview but doing it the way I'm doing it allows users to adjust their table easily without getting into the code of what I'm making. I'm not sure if I explained the tab thing correctly. Let's say this: Copying row one of my datatable to the clipboard results in 10 columns when pasted into excel...copying from datagridview results in one column. I THINK this is because dgv removes the [tab].

Comment: Are there any other spaces except for ones that are meant to be split by in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have numerous options available, but in most cases you'll need to perform some looping one way or another - however even with 1000+ records it's performance hardly takes a hit.

So for the first couple of options let's assume I have the following setup - keeping with your one `DataGridViewColumn` idea:

```
Me.table = New DataTable()
Me.table.Columns.Add("Data", GetType(String))

For i As Integer = 0 To 999
    Dim x As Integer = i * 4
    Dim data As String = String.Format("Result {0}" & vbTab & "Result {1}" & vbTab & "Result {2}" & vbTab & "Result {3}", x + 1, x + 2, x + 3, x + 4)
    Me.table.Rows.Add(data)
Next

Me.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
Me.dataGridView1.DataSource = Me.table
```

**Possible Solutions**

1. Loop through the `DataTable`, concatenate the data, and set the clipboard text:

   ```
   Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
       Dim content As String = String.Empty

       For Each row As DataRow In Me.table.Rows
           content = String.Format("{0}" & vbLf & "{1}", content, row.ItemArray(0).ToString())
       Next

       content = content.TrimStart(ControlChars.Lf)
       Clipboard.SetText(content)
   End Sub
   ```
2. Loop through the `DataGridView.Rows`, concatenate the data, and set the clipboard text:

   ```
   Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
       Dim content As String = String.Empty

       For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.dataGridView1.Rows
           content = String.Format("{0}" & vbLf & "{1}", content, row.Cells(0).Value.ToString())
       Next

       content = content.TrimStart(ControlChars.Lf)
       Clipboard.SetText(content)
   End Sub
   ```

---

- And to make the grid *look* a little better for both option 1 and 2, since the display seems to ignore tabs:

  ```
  Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) _
  Handles dataGridView1.CellFormatting
      Dim value As String = e.Value.ToString().Replace(vbTab, "     ")
      e.Value = value
  End Sub
  ```

  With that your grid might look like:

  [image: dgv with one column]

---

3. In addition to the original setup and instead of binding to the original `DataTable`, split the table's data by the tabs and display them in separate columns:

   ```
   Dim splitTable As New DataTable()

   For Each row As DataRow In Me.table.Rows
       Dim splitItems = row.ItemArray(0).ToString().Split(ControlChars.Tab)

       For i As Integer = splitTable.Columns.Count To splitItems.Length - 1
           splitTable.Columns.Add(String.Empty, GetType(String))
       Next

       splitTable.Rows.Add(splitItems)
   Next

   Me.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
   Me.dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText
   Me.dataGridView1.DataSource = splitTable
   ```

   Then you can use the built-in clipboard method for the `DataGridView`:

   ```
   Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
       Me.dataGridView1.SelectAll()
       Clipboard.SetDataObject(Me.dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent())
   End Sub
   ```

   With that your grid might look like:

   [image: dgv with multiple columns]

---

For all three options, clicking `button1` to copy the data and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Excel will produce:

[image: excel results]

Note that [Wrap Text will be on by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33529140/3773066).

---

**Pros:**

Options 1 and 2 leave the user-selected cells intact. Option 3 looks better with separated `DataGridView` columns.

**Cons:**

Options 1 and 2 can look less clean pending the data. Option 3 selects all cells, losing the user's previous selected cells.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. What an incredibly thorough answer. I went with option 3. I did move the datatable column creation outside of the "For each row in table.rows" loop, but it otherwise worked like a charm!
I wasn't having any luck with setting the datasource before but I think I might just skip the initial table creation and create the final delimited table directly from my input.
I'm working on 15 "rep" points but I'll be back for reference I'm sure. BEST ANSWER!

Comment: Glad to hear it. I placed the column creation there because I wasn't sure of what your column size might be or if they were at all variable (doubtful, but I erred on caution's side).